# Get all email addresses from a domain

Tags: google-apps-script

Can I get the complete list of email addresses from a domain with Google Apps Script? (Like the "To:" Gmail field shows my contacts addresses and domain addresses)? I don't have an account with administrative privileges, so I'm wondering if this can be done from a standard users' account.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this from a standard domain user account.

Only administrators have access to all users' email addresses.